# List multiplication

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a the following code:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {13000, 3}];

x = 1;
y = 2.3;
z = 0.7;

data[[All, 1]] = data[[All, 1]]*x; 
data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]]*y; 
data[[All, 3]] = data[[All, 3]]*z;
```

**How would you solve the recalculation of `data`?**

Comment: What do you mean by "solve the recalculation"?

Comment: Maybe, you would like to know about `TimesBy` (`*=`)? Example: `data[[All, 1]] *= x`;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your vector to a diagonal matrix, and then use [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot):

```
data = RandomReal[1,{13000,3}];
data1 = data . DiagonalMatrix[{x, y, z}]; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000051, Null}

Another very fast approach suggested by @LLlAMnYP (making sure to pack the vector first):

```
m = Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ {x, y, z};
data2 = Transpose[data] m //Transpose; //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.000085, Null}

Compare with your approach:

```
data[[All, 1]] = data[[All, 1]] x;
data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]] y;
data[[All, 3]] = data[[All, 3]] z;

data == data1 == data2
```

> True

Comment: `Transpose[data] {x,y,z} // Transpose` is competitive too, especially if instead of `{x,y,z}` we have a packed array.

Comment: Thank you and also to @LLlAMnYP for the solutions ... great.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you would like to get to know `TimesBy`, a.k.a. `*=`.

```
data0 = RandomReal[1, {1300000, 3}];
x = 1;
y = 2.3;
z = 0.7;
```

The original approach:

```
data = data0;
AbsoluteTiming[
 data[[All, 1]] = data[[All, 1]]*x;
 data[[All, 2]] = data[[All, 2]]*y;
 data[[All, 3]] = data[[All, 3]]*z;
 ]
data1 = data;

(* {0.097083, Null} *)
```

A naive approach with `TimesBy`:

```
data = data0;
AbsoluteTiming[
 data[[All, 1]] *= x;
 data[[All, 2]] *= y;
 data[[All, 3]] *= z;
 ]
data2 = data;

(* {0.104508, Null} *)
```

Seemingly, this does not help. Hence another approach with `TimesBy`:

```
data = data0;
AbsoluteTiming[
 data *= ConstantArray[Developer`ToPackedArray[N[{x, y, z}]], Length[data]];
 ]
data3 = data;

(* {0.021616, Null} *)
```

... and a check for correct results:

```
data1 == data2
data1 == data3

(* True *)
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thank you vey much for you help.